# Making sure table/materialized view created before continuing next command on Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse, clickhouse-go

I'm using [clickhouse-go](https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-go), sometimes when I run create multiple materialized view, then query from those materialized view it shows success, but sometimes failed because the materialized view not yet created (`table default.the_mv_name doesn't exists`)

Is there any workaround so the `db.Exec("CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW .... POPULATE AS SELECT ...")` only return when it's successfully created. Something like `SELECT ... FROM bla FINAL` when querying.

Or there's no workaround, so I have to loop and check `system.columns` table until it's ready?

for non-replicated engine - there's around 50% chance it's happened, for replicated engine - almost always happened

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with clickhouse-client? There is no sense to run CREATE .. POPULATE against replicated tables, data will be doubled/tripled.

Comment: but without populate, the materialized view will be empty '__')

Comment: https://den-crane.github.io/Everything_you_should_know_about_materialized_views_commented.pdf